# Move glyphicon div higher

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem where i can't get the glypicon to the center of the input field that its next to. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        .mydiv {
            font-size: 100px;
        }

        .glyphicon-search {
            font-size: 30px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="mydiv">
        <input class="input" type='text' placeholder="ABC" autocomplete="off"><div class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

And here is what it looks like:
[image]

I wish to move the image just a bit higher as the arrow indicates. How is that possible?

Comment: Try making the `line-height` of  glyphicon `100px`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `vertical-align` on the icon to affect that. Or `display: flex; align-items: center` on the parent to vertically align everything. You can also make micro adjustments using `transform: translateY();`

I'm using `flex` here with the other 2 options commented out.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <style>
    .mydiv {
            font-size: 100px;
        }

        .glyphicon-search {
            font-size: 30px;
          /*vertical-align: middle;
          transform: translateY(-10px);*/
        }
    .mydiv {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="mydiv">
    <input class="input" type='text' placeholder="ABC" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```